# How to use @WebServlet Annotation with Apache Tomcat 8.0.27

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I'm using ***Java EE 7 Web*** with ***Apache Tomcat 8.0.25***

On my Usr login, when I verify if the usr exist and it's administrator or normal usr I return from Servlet (POST) an "OK" or "OK-ADM" then I do this on Ajax:

```
login: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "loginUsr.usr",
            data: {
                usr: $("#usr").val(),
                pass: $("#pass").val()
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data.estatus === "OK")
                {
                    setInterval(function(){ 
                        location.href = "http://localhost:8080/WebPage/uploadPDF.jsp"; //HERE IS THE SEVERE THING
                    }, 3000);
                } else if(data.estatus === "OK-ADM"){
                    setInterval(function(){
                        location.href = "http://localhost:8080/WebPage/admLog.jsp"; //HERE IS ANOTHER SEVERE THING
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Which is totally wrong! For security reasons...

So it occurred to me create a ***Servlet*** to be responsible for redirect to the correct page, the **Usr** is already in session at this point so I just need to validate if it's admin or common usr, I was thinking on doing something like this:

```
login: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "loginUsr.usr",
            data: {
                usr: $("#usr").val(),
                pass: $("#pass").val()
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data.estatus === "OK")
                {
                    setInterval(function(){ 
                        document.location.href = 'access.acc'; //The New Servlet
                    }, 3000);
                } else if(data.estatus === "OK-ADM"){

                    setInterval(function(){
                        document.location.href = 'access.acc'; //The New Servlet
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Then in the ***Servlet***:

```
@WebServlet(name = "access", urlPatterns = {"*.acc"}) //BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK
public class access extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String accion = request.getServletPath();
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        Usuario usr = null;

        try {
            try{
                usr = (Usuario)request.getSession().getAttribute("usuario");
            } catch(Exception e){
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);  
            }
            if("/access.acc".equals(accion)){
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    if(usr.getTipoUsuario() == 1 || usr.getTipoUsuario() == 2 || usr.getTipoUsuario() == 3) { 
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("admLog.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    } else if(usr.getTipoUsuario() == 0){
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("uploadPDF.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    }
                    out.close();
            } else if("/salir.acc".equals(accion)){
                if(null == usr){
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    session.invalidate();
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    out.close(); 
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the message pops over IDE:

```
package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

It's there a way to use this functionality on newer Java Application?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Regards!

Comment: It sounds like your build environment is set for something before Java/EE 6 when the annotation was introduced though it could also be a build issue.  Check your settings to make sure you're targeting EE 6 or 7 and let us know how you're building.  As an unrelated note, rolling your own security like this is a bit dangerous - if someone knows the admLog.jsp URL can they get to it directly?

Comment: U don't know if this help but this is how I have the web.xml
<web-app 
version="3.1" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem.

First, My **javax.servlet.jar** it was not correct, so downloading the updated [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar](https://mavenbrowse.pauldoo.com/index/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/) solves the problem of:

```
package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

Second, on my *Ajax* function when it's success(before validating if the **Usr** exist on DB) I call the servlet like this:

```
success: function (data)
{
    if (data.estatus === "OK")
    {
        setInterval(function(){ 
            document.location.href = 'acceso.acc'; //here is some magic.
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        //error message
    }
}
```

The **document.location.href** calls the **acceso.acc** *Servlet* (If you want to do this you need to remember than you first need **the user on a session**)

```
package some.package.servlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.al.entity.Usuario;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(name = "access", urlPatterns = {"*.acc"}) //This is how I receive all the .acc routes
public class access extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String accion = request.getServletPath();
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        Usuario usr = null;
        try {
            try{
                usr = (Usuario)request.getSession().getAttribute("usuario");
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            if("/acceso.acc".equals(accion)){
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    if(usr.getTipoUsuario() == 1 || usr.getTipoUsuario() == 2 || usr.getTipoUsuario() == 3) { 
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("admLog.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    } else if(usr.getTipoUsuario() == 0){
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("uploadPDF.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    }
                    out.close();
            } else if("/salir.acc".equals(accion)){
                if(null == usr){
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    session.invalidate();
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    out.close(); 
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Doing this I don't need to include the ***.acc** on the **web.xml**

Many thanks and Regards.